# Link EXTERNAL Scrollbar to Textbox in C# (Using theme for form)

Tags: c#, .net

Hello I was wondering if I could link an external scrollbar to my textbox, due to the theme not having a builtin scrollbar feature, otherwise I would have set the property for it already. Thanks!.

The theme I am using is called "Net Seal Theme"